# How long should I wait for a flag to be reviewed?

Tags: discussion, moderation, flagging

I raised a flag on a question on the main Puzzling site on August 10th (2 weeks ago today). One of my subsequent flags has been marked as helpful, but the flag from 2 weeks ago has not yet been addressed. Should I keep waiting? If not, what can I do to move the process forward?

Comment: What kind of flag is it? Custom flags can have a much longer response time than simple No Longer Needed ones. (Having said that, I just checked and my oldest pending flag is an NLN from June 14)

Comment: It is in fact a custom flag @bobble

Comment: 2 weeks? I raised a custom flag on 6 Feb that was only handled on 9 Jun.

Comment: @Randal'Thor I didn't really have a baseline. Probably could have waited longer, I suppose.

Comment: Depends on the flag. I'd certainly expect *almost all* flags to be resolved in less than two weeks, unless it's something really tricky maybe that requires CM escalation to resolve or a lot of mod discussion to decide what to do. Was just commenting to show the problem is even bigger than what you've noticed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sorry for the delay! I can't speak for the other mods, but I've been a bit busy recently. I'd occasionally handled some of the easier flags, but hadn't gone through the queue recently.

To answer your question, "what can I do to move the process forward?"... well, this meta post was a reasonable course of action. And it worked - I've now handled the flag in question (as well as all other outstanding flags)!